# Como fazer 2 consultas em banco diferente com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho 2 bancos online, e gostaria de fazer uma consulta nos 2 bancos como monto a conexão?

```
$Conn_1 = mysql_connect("teste","teste","teste");
$Db1 = mysql_select_db("BANCO1");

$Conn_2 = mysql_connect("teste","teste","teste");
$Db2 = mysql_select_db("BANCO2");
```

E depois como eu digo qual `query` vai pra 1 e qual vai pra outro?

Comment: Os bancos são no mesmo servidor ?

Comment: Um local e outro na Kinghost... Servidores diferentes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No final da sua query  `$Conn_1 ou $Conn_2`  você seta sua conexão com db, veja no exemplo abaixo:

```
$Conn_1 = mysql_connect("teste","teste","teste");
$Db1 = mysql_select_db("BANCO1");

$Conn_2 = mysql_connect("teste","teste","teste");
$Db2 = mysql_select_db("BANCO2");

$Query_Banco_2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tabela ', $Conn_1 );

Query_Banco_1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tabela ', $Conn_2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

As funções mysql_* não devem ser mais usadas deve-se optar pelo MySQLi caso não seja possível basta informar o quarto argumento de `mysql_connect()` como true, isso vai criar uma nova conexão. Ela deve ser passada em `mysql_query()` com a respectiva consulta.

`mysql_select_db()` retorna uma booleano dizendo se foi possível acessar a base ou não.

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
$Conn_1 = mysql_connect("teste","teste","teste", true);
mysql_select_db("BANCO1", $Conn_1);
mysql_query("select ... from ... ", $Conn_1);


$Conn_2 = mysql_connect("teste","teste","teste", true);
mysql_select_db("BANCO2", $Conn_2);
mysql_query("select ... from ... ", $Conn_2);
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)